# TFS Build Xamarin Forms netstandard2.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

Im trying to setup a Build for my Xamarin Forms project targeting net standard2.0

The Build definition looks like:

1. Get Source
2. InstallNuget 4.6.2
3. NugetRestore
4. Build Xamarin iOS using VSMac as BuildTool

im using the newest build agent on my local macbook (just for testing).
This is the error im Getting:

> Errors in ...
>    Package Portable.Ninject 3.3.1 is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Is the $(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;
 not Recognized?

Here is the full Output from TFS: https://gist.github.com/Darth-Alex/1c5fb703fbfcdde54cb84fd2ee5fca0f

Comment: [submit it in github](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/issues) to get a .net standard 2.0 comaptible version

Comment: not needed! it works well with the PCL fallback. The only problem is the TFS Build Task which fails.

Comment: did yot resolved this?

Comment: @Merian I moved to Autofac... Now everything is fine :)